# How to remove a symbolic link to a directory?

Tags: linux, bash, symbolic-link

I am using Ubuntu 8.10, Bash and I made a symbolic link with the following command:

```
ln -s ../test5
```

I want to remove it now but my rm fails:

```
rm -Rf test5/
rm: cannot remove `test5/`: Not a directory

rm test5/
rm: cannot remove directory `test5/`: Is a directory

rmdir test5/
rmdir: test5/: Not a directory

rm -r test5/
rm: cannot remove `test5/`: Not a directory

ls -l
 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 peter peter    8 Jul 20 15:30 test5 -> ../test5/
```

How can I remove my symbolic link?

Comment: TIP: `rm -r link/` deletes the content on the target

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Remove the trailing slash:

With prompt:

> `$ rm test5`

Without prompt:

> `$ rm -f test5`

Comment: It says `permission denied`.

Comment: Without trailing slash. So `test5/` is incorrect.

Answer (score 25):

Try `rm test5`
(without the trailing slash).

The slash indicates that 'test5' is a directory whereas it's actually a file *linking* to a directory.

Answer (score 16):

You can run removing the trailing slash:

```
$ rm test5
```

This will remove the file (i.e. the symlink).

Alternatively you may use unlink:

```
$ unlink test5
```

Again you must omit the trailing slash since you are attempting to unlink the symlink not the directory.

Answer (score 1):

The issue in the OP is the trailing `/`, so `test5/` throws an error but `test5` works.

I prefer to use `unlink` rather than `rm` as my intention is clearer and there is no chance of mistakenly removing the real directory instead of the link.  Make sure that there is no trailing `/` after the directory name, e.g.:

```
unlink test5
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you use autocomplete to name the link that you want to delete you may not see a trailing slash but it's 'half there' and that invisible slash still gives the delete error when trying to remove that link.

So in that case type out character by character the link to be deleted as "test5"  as eg. `rm test5`.

Comment: Never heard of invisible slash. What shell does this?

Comment: I think it's possibly a reference to the character being hidden by linewrap+cursor?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with an empty directory with two symlinks.  rmdir won't work in Kubuntu 20.10.  It answers "directory not empty".  rm says it's a directory.

Answer (score -1):

I feel silly asking, but have you tried `rm -r`?
Since it's a symbolic link it shouldn't delete the target.

Edit: Just tried it, it's correct

Edit 2: rmdir says in its first line of the man page it deletes empty directories.  I would think because it's a link it had the directory bit checked on its file properties, but because rmdir doesn't suspect that being the case it spits errors.  Just use rm -r

Comment: This will ask me to delete the files in the directory, that's not what I want, I want to delete only the link

Comment: The asking was because interactive was defined in my .profile. Added the response to rm -r. It still doesn't work.

Comment: You left the trailing '/'  that's why it failed