# Unlink (remove) directory symlink

Tags: linux, bash, symbolic-link, rm, ln

I did:

```
ln -s /DATA/ ./base_DATA/
```

and I'd like to unlink. Simply:

```
unlink ./base_DATA
```

but... `unlink: cannot unlink './base_DATA': Is a directory`

According to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/9181/how-to-remove-a-symbolic-link-to-a-directory) answer (and many other online) the problem is usually the trailing space in the unlink command. But I get this error regardless.

Any ideas how to tackle this?

Comment: `unlink` is not the opposite of `ls -s`. It is basically same as `rm` (in this case. `rm` has more powers.).

Comment: If using gnu `ln` then consider using the `-t` and `-T` option. They are designed to make the arguments to `cp`, `mv`, and `ln` unambiguous.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor doesn't `rm -r` delete the contents of linked diretory?

Comment: `rm -r` will remove a directory and everything in it. It will also remove a single file (including a symlink). `rm` can also take a list of filenames. `unlink` excepts one filename, and only removes single files. Note: nether delete, they remove/unlink directory entries. If a file has zero references (no entry in any directory, no open files), then it is deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`./base_DATA/` is a normal directory that existed before. Your `ln` command created a symlink *inside* it. The symlink is `./base_DATA/DATA`. You can unlink it:

```
unlink ./base_DATA/DATA
```

Comment: I see, this makes sense. And works obviously. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

on Red Hat, when you had directory A and did

ln -s  A  B

successfully, and now would like to unlink B do:

mv  A  AA

rm  B

mv AA A

and you are back to your original directory name A without the soft link.